# Why is the score the same as the high score when the game restarts?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I’m trying every possible solution, but have a look at this. The points are shown, and the high score too, but the high score is always the same as the score. When I restart the game, the score is not 0, but same the as the high score. If you got 6 points as a high score, the score is also 6 points. I hope you get it.

I took a screenshot. It just started and I didn't hit any enemy. the score should be 0, but is the same as the high score.

[image: A screenshot of the problem]

This is health script that is attached to the enemy:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static HealthScript instance;
    public int hp = 1;
    private GUIText scoreReference;
    private GUIText highscoreReference;
    private static int _highscore = -1;
    public int highscore { 
        get { if (_highscore == -1) 
            _highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore", 0);
            return _highscore; 
        }
        set {
            if (value > _highscore) {
                _highscore = value;
                highscoreReference.text = _highscore.ToString();
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", _highscore);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool isEnemy = true;


    private static int points;
    public void Damage(int damageCount) {
        hp -= damageCount;

        if (hp <= 0)
        {
            // Dead!
            Destroy(gameObject);
            points++;
            scoreReference.text = points.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void gameEnd() {

        points = highscore;
        points = 0;
    }

    //update from previous code
    void Start()
    {

    scoreReference = GameObject.Find("Score").guiText;
    highscoreReference = GameObject.Find("HighScore").guiText;
    scoreReference.text = points.ToString(); 
    highscoreReference.text = highscore.ToString ();
    instance = this;

}
```

and this is my player script where the gameover method in this class

```
void OnDestroy()
{
    // Game Over.
    // Add the script to the parent because the current game
    // object is likely going to be destroyed immediately.
    transform.parent.gameObject.AddComponent ();
    HealthScript.instance.gameEnd ();
}
```

---

THE PROBLEM SOLVED. JUST CHANGE THIS "points = highscore;" TO "highscore = points;". I DON'T KNOW BUT DOES IT MATTER TO BE LIKE THAT? I HOPE SOMEONE CAN EXPLAIN THAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a duplicate here.

```
    scoreReference = GameObject.Find("Score").guiText;
    highscoreReference = GameObject.Find("HighScore").guiText;
    scoreReference.text = points.ToString(); //KEEP THIS
    highscoreReference.text = highscore.ToString();
    scoreReference = GameObject.Find("Score").guiText;
    scoreReference.text = highscore.ToString(); //REMOVE THIS - THIS IS A DUPLICATE
```

Comment: thanks, i'm glad to be able fix this. Also i removed the points= 0 at the start method.

Comment: hey suddenly, it's do not update the score after restart.  @Droid Chris

Comment: can you elaborate please

Comment: it's already solved. JUST CHANGE THIS "points = highscore;" TO "highscore = points;". Btw, thanks!